# download attribute different behaviour for 2 links

Tags: html, attributes

below are two links with download attribute.
clicking on both gives different result, why?

```
 <a href="https://www.w3schools.com/images/myw3schoolsimage.jpg" download>
  dnld
</a>
<br>
<a href="https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t45.1600-4/28204217_6081249221877_6688541583534456832_n.png?oh=9262305ce4d55f669767f01c1be364b1&amp;oe=5B06C1A9" download >Download</a>
```

w3schools link downloads the image where as the other one simply opens the image.

Answer (score -1):

because the extension should be displayed at end of url

```html
<a href="https://www.w3schools.com/images/myw3schoolsimage.jpg" download>
  dnld
</a>
<br>
<a href="https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t45.1600-4/28204217_6081249221877_6688541583534456832_n.png" download >Download</a>
```

Comment: upload the image to img.ur and get direct link from there